# PHP MYSQL query, only search in rows where field is true

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a question where I can't find an answer for.

How can I preform a search query only where the current_version is 1? I have tried the query below but that didn't worked.

```
SELECT labtest_id AS id, 
       labtest_name AS name, 
       labtest_request_code, 
       labtest_synonym, 
       labtest_current_version, 
       labtest_version 
FROM labtests 
WHERE labtest_current_version = 1 AND labtest_name LIKE %imap% OR labtest_request_code 
LIKE %imap% OR labtest_synonym LIKE %imap%
```

**searchkey = test5**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name  | request_code | synonym | current_version | version |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | test1 | 74532        | one     | 1               | 1.00    |
| 2  | test2 | 74432        | two     | 1               | 0.00    |
| 3  | test3 | 78962        | three   | 0               | 2.05    |
| 4  | test4 | 72111        | four    | 0               | 1.07    |
| 5  | test5 | 90322        | five    | 1               | 2.00    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So in this example the search query need to show row 1

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name  | request_code | synonym | current_version | version |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | test5 | 90322        | five    | 1               | 2.00    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what is 'labtest_' before every filed in query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing parentheses arount your `OR` clauses and quotes around your strings:

```
SELECT labtest_id AS id, 
    labtest_name AS name, 
    labtest_request_code, 
    labtest_synonym, 
    labtest_current_version, 
    labtest_version
FROM labtests
WHERE labtest_current_version = 1
  AND (labtest_name LIKE '%imap%'
      OR labtest_request_code LIKE '%imap%'
      OR labtest_synonym LIKE '%imap%')
```

If you omit the parentheses, the two last `OR` clauses will return rows whatever the `labtest_current_version` value, [due to operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) and boolean laws.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your OR conditions like:

```
WHERE labtest_current_version = 1 AND (labtest_name LIKE %imap% OR labtest_request_code LIKE %imap% OR labtest_synonym LIKE %imap%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to separate the AND / OR operators by grouping the OR parts with `()`

```
SELECT labtest_id AS id, 
    labtest_name AS name, 
    labtest_request_code, 
    labtest_synonym, 
    labtest_current_version, 
    labtest_version
FROM labtests
WHERE labtest_current_version = 1 AND (labtest_name LIKE %imap% OR labtest_request_code LIKE %imap% OR labtest_synonym LIKE %imap%)
```